# State is always undefined when using the @connectTo decorator in a config pipeline step in Aurelia Store

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-store

I have an Aurelia app using [Aurelia Store](https://github.com/aurelia/store). I'm having some trouble when using the `@connectTo` decorator in an Aurelia pipeline step.

I have added the following step to my config pipeline:

```
config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AuthorizeStep);
```

And this step looks like:

```
@connectTo()
export class AuthorizeStep {
  state: State;

  run(navigationInstruction, next) {
    if (navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions().find(x => x.config.isAdmin)) 
    {
      if (!this.state.user.isAdmin) {
        return next.cancel();
      }
    }

    return next();
  }
}
```

However, my state is always undefined. Looking at other parts of my project, I can see the state and user are being populated, but it seems like in this `AuthorizeStep` it doesn't seem to work.

I think this issue may be due to the fact that my `AuthorizeStep` doesn't have a `bind` lifecycle method, but if so, what can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maintainers of Aurelia responded (only after I raised an issue on their GitHub) [here](https://github.com/aurelia/store/issues/35).

Basically, as the bind lifecycle does not exist within this class, the `@connectTo` decorator won't work. Instead, I will need to manually inject the Store and subscribing to the state.

Comment: This is not an answer, you should provide the relevant information from the link to make this a "good answer". https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer